# inheritance with angularjs .service()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

I have a ServiceA() in module A and variable item is used in html.

```
angular.module("ModuleA").service("ServiceA", function () {
  var item=[];
  this.get(){
    item.push("A");
  }
});
```

Controller.js

```
angular.module("ModuleX").controller("Ctrl", function (ServiceA) {
   $scope.service=ServiceA;
});
```

HTML:

```
 <h1>{{service.item}}
 </h1>
```

i am trying to achieve inheritance using angularjs .service(),I want to make serviceA() in moduleA as base service and create a service serviceB() in moduleB and this should inherit base service(serviceA()) and update variable 'item' in serviceA().

Controller code and html code remains same.

Is it possible? Is this a good approach? Can we achieve inheritance/abstraction using angularjs .service()?

```
angular.module("ModuleB").service("serviceB", function (serviceA) {
  serviceA.item="B";
});
```

Comment: Actually  you can but you must inject as a module dependency the module of serviceA.
angular.module('ModuleB',['ModuleA']).service("serviceB",function(serviceA)...

Answer (score 0):

1. Whenever you define a module, you should pass a empty array or
   dependencies as the second argument. i.e. `angular.module("ModuleA",
   [])` or `angular.module("ModuleA", ['someDependent'])`.
2. The service is in one module whereas the controller is in the other module. So, you need to create a relation between them `angular.module("ModuleX", ["ModuleA"])`.
3. You are not returning anything from the service and you have written the method in wrong way.

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lbm8475MlWI2bLRq81Ca?p=preview)**

**Working Code**

```
angular.module("ModuleA", []).service("ServiceA", function () {
  var item=[];
  this.get = function(){
    item.push("A");
    return item;
  }
});

angular.module("ModuleX", ["ModuleA"]).controller("Ctrl", function ($scope, ServiceA) {
   $scope.service = ServiceA.get();
   console.log($scope);
});
```